# What's the most optimized way to add a wordlist in my Windows Store application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

What I need to do is to add a list of words in my application.
I need this because when the user clicks on a button, I want the application to retrieve 3 random words from this list.
So, how could I add these words in my Windows Store application? I heard that databases are not supported in this kind of applications, so which way should I follow?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the word list, and what kind of size of objects you wish to store.

If it is a small word list, then you could use isolated storage. I like to use a GenericObjectStorageHelper.

http://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/

Alternatively (and also my recommendation for most scenarios) is to deliver the 3 words over a webservice. WinRT is designed to be mobile (supports the surface etc..) and implementing a separated service layer is a recommended pattern. This will be especially useful if you have 1k+ of records to pick from, as it will minimize the storage requirements of your application.

Creating a WCF Web Service :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/05/11/getting-started-building-a-wcf-web-service.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I want the game to be playable offline, so I guess I will choose the first option. Is a wordlist of 500 words considered small?

Comment: Yes i'm sure that would be fine. However if you find yourself having to persist a lot of information (as a large game that can be played offline would do i imagine) - then there is always SQLLite : http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that It was compatibile! Thanks a lot! :D